# SQL Query updating a range of fields - MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am having some trouble forming this sql query.
I want to run a mysql query as such:

Inside "TableX" I want to update "ColumnY" for all the entries in "ColumnZ" that has a value ranging from 2887 - 3474

Hope that was clear. I would run this in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax for updating a record inside a table is

```
update <table_name>
set <column_name_1>=<new_value> [, <col_name_2>=<new_value_2> ...]
where <condition>;
```

So, your query will look like

```
update TableX  
set ColumnY='New Content'
where ColumnZ > 2886 and ColumnZ <3475;
```

**Update**

As mentioned by [A C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4096667/a-c)

If ColumnZ holds floating point number, then above query will return all such records where `ColumnZ ∈ (2886,2887]` and `ColumnZ ∈ [3474,3475)`

To model conditions in such cases, you should take care of the limits (inclusive or exclusive) and type of the column.

Comment: Note that this query will include e.g. 2886.5 in the update, whereas the one from @BorLaze will not.  This query could, however, be rewritten as `where ColumnZ >= 2887 and ColumnZ <= 3474` to make them equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

```
update TableX
set ColumnY = 'zzz'
where ColumnZ between 2887 and 3474
```